# Configure Office 365 POP3 Account with OAuth2 in Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, authentication, azure, pop3, oauth2

Recently Microsoft deactivated Office 365 Basic Authentication, causing all POP3 email accounts in my organization configured in Outlook 2016 client to stop working and display a password error.

If I set up those accounts again as new i can use them in Outlook 2016, but it only configure them as IMAP, which is not what I need in my organization. We need them to continue connecting via POP3.

I downloaded Mozilla Thunderbird and was able to configure the POP3 accounts with OAuth 2, seamlessly and without any additional configuration in the Azure panel. Thunderbird simply opened the new authentication prompt, the Office 365 window asked if I authorized it, I clicked OK, and everything was configured. Simple.

It seems odd that the same thing cannot be done in the Microsoft Outlook 2016 clients; at least I couldn't find a way to do it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make POP3 work with OAuth 2 in Outlook 2016 so that we don't have to switch to Thunderbird on all machines in the organization? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is very regrettable to tell you that the Exchange Team have no plans to add OAuth support to POP3/IMAP4 in Outlook. They claim that adding OAuth to POP3/IMAP4 only have some alternative options like Thunderbrid, OWA or any other app that supports it.

For more information ,you can info [Microsoft Exchange Team's blog.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437)

Answer (score 1):

As is Microsoft Exchange Team's developer said in the Microsoft Blog:[enter link description here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437). It is certainly that adding OAuth support to POP3/IMAP4 in Outlook is still need to be developed.
[image]